# Haskell List generating infinite loop

Tags: list, haskell

I am completely new to Haskell and came across this problem where I have a list 'a' constituting two lists and another list 'b'.
But when I do a = b:a and try to print list 'a' afterwards, it starts an infinite loop every time, I am not sure why this is happening. Any help is much appreciated!

```
Prelude> a
[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
Prelude> b
[6,7,8]
Prelude> a = b:a
Prelude> a
```

Comment: I'd still expect output, despite the infinite loop...

Comment: @Carl it would be an infinite list `[[6,7,8],[6,7,8],[6,7,8],[6,7,8]...`

Comment: the `a` in the new definition `a = b:a` has nothing to do with the previous definition `a = [[....]]`. same name, new variable; old variable is inaccessible, "shadowed".

Comment: @MeowcolmLaw Yes, that's the part I don't get, why does it generate an infinite loop? Shouldn't b:a , append list b in the beginning of list a and then update the list to which 'a' is pointing?

Comment: @PriyavartRajain well Haskell does not work in this way. Maybe you shall visit the answer in the blue box in this page :)